# Make Sublime Text Laravel Generator Work

Tags: php, laravel-4, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04, sublime-text-plugin

I've just set up my LAMP environment for development and installed the Laravel generator plugin for Sublime Text. But whenever I try to make a view, I get this error at the bottom of the Sublime Text editor.

```
Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 6131
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

I am new to Ubuntu(14.04). I have tried installing `php5-json` but still doesn't work.